# Need a better Internet browser for Windows CE netbook

Tags: internet, browser, netbook, web, windows-ce

I just got a Windows CE 5.0 netbook (shown below). Despite being cheap I thought I could get somewhere with it.

Are there any Internet browsers I can download? I know regular Firefox and Internet Explorer won't work and I honestly don't even know what it has; all it says is WEB.

[image]

Comment: What "flavor" of CE is it running? Got a link to the model or specs?

Comment: It has Windows CE 5.0 on it, it's very downgraded

Answer (score 2):

There are WinCE browsers suggested [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111112160903/http://superuser.com/questions/24263/is-there-a-free-internet-browser-available-for-windows-ce).

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're probably stuck with the version of IE that's on there. I had a netbook just like this and took it back after one day because I just couldn't do ANYTHING with it. All the Windows CE we browsers I've found (and believe me, I've spent a long time looking!) are either .cab files that will only run on mobile phones (you may be able to get software to convert the .cab files to executables that'll run under Windows - .exe files - but I didn't try as I'd given up hope...), or just won't install under CE, and these netbooks are generally very, very limited in upgrade potential. Mine did not allow changing the operating system, and the version of IE on it was so ancient and slow that it wouldn't even load Facebook properly, even with image support turned off, and it wasn't flash or java compatible - well, not to modern standards anyway. I was so disappointed that it could do so little (certainly not what I'd classify as an Internet browser when it could barely load the most simplistic of web pages), it was a shame as the unit itself was so dinky and cute...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a prototype of a Windows Mobile browser?  The Zune HD's OS is based off of Windows CE, and has an impressive browser...

Have you tried Mozilla Firefox's mobile version?

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fennec

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/

*It appears that Mozilla Fennec is still in developement stages...may be able to find a beta...*

Comment: It has Windows CE 5.0 on it, it's very downgraded

Answer (score 1):

K-Meleon is a small browser for windows based on the gecko engine from Mozilla.
I don't if it works under Windows CE, but I think it's worth a try?